# Unable to Log into Magento Admin Panel

Tags: html, css, magento

When I go to my Admin Panel in Magento, I noticed the page doesn't seem to load correctly, as I can only see the enter *username* and *password*. The Panel has not loaded correctly and the submit button is missing or cut off. I am confused as to why?

Please see the screen captured link [here.](https://peacewithin.net.au/store/screen-capture-magento.png)

Many thanks for any advice. So far I think I may have to reinstall?

Cheers

Comment: View the source code and see if it's returning an error message at the bottom.  Also check your var/logs folder for error logs.

Comment: I noticed this error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Which means you have an issue with your server.  You'll have to debug using the server log files.  If you don't have access to those or have no idea, contact your host.

Comment: Argh excellent. Will do. Thanks for the advice.